# Rollup ignores files that only exports

Tags: es6-modules, rollup, rollupjs

I am making esm modules from rollup with following configuration:

```
  ...,
  output: [
  {
    dir: "./build",
    format: "esm",
    sourcemap: true,
    preserveModules: true,
    preserveModulesRoot: "src",
  },
],
```

The generated output creates each file according to the content, but I have divided each module into subfolders and in this example, the folder `Components` have a file that includes and exports each sub-component

[image]

`components.ts` looks like this:

```
export { default as BNButton } from "./BNButton/BNButton";
export { default as BNCard } from "./BNCard/BNCard";
export { default as BNDonutChart } from "./BNDonutChart/BNDonutChart";
export { default as BNFooter } from "./BNFooter/BNFooter";
export { default as BNHeader } from "./BNHeader/BNHeader";
export { default as BNInlineSvgIcon } from "./BNInlineSvgIcon/BNInlineSvgIcon";
export { default as BNJumpToNavigation } from "./BNJumpToNavigation/BNJumpToNavigation";
export { default as BNSideNavigation } from "./BNSideNavigation/BNSideNavigation";
export { default as BNTopMobileNavigation } from "./BNTopMobileNavigation/BNTopMobileNavigation";
export { default as BNTopNavigation } from "./BNTopNavigation/BNTopNavigation";
```

`index.ts` on root `/src` includes `Components/components.ts`

When rollup runs and generate the files, `compoents.ts` is just ignored and not generated. Rollup jumps over this file and imports the files directly into `index.js` without the `components.js`.

That is bad because I would like to use `components.js` and import the modules also from this file. Does anyone know why rollup is doing this, and is there a way to make rollup not do this but rather generate a `components.js` which exports the imported modules?